# Spring and hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

How do I get Spring to load Hibernate's properties from `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

We're using Spring and JPA (with Hibernate as the implementation). Spring's `applicationContext.xml` specifies the JPA dialect and Hibernate properties:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In this configuration, Spring is reading all the Hibernate properties via applicationContext.xml . When I create a `hibernate.cfg.xml` (located at the root of my classpath, the same level as META-INF), Hibernate doesn't read it at all (it's completely ignored).

What I'm trying to do is configure Hibernate second level cache by inserting the cache properties in `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<cache 
    usage="transactional|read-write|nonstrict-read-write|read-only"
    region="RegionName"
    include="all|non-lazy"
/>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
<bean
    id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="configLocation">    
        <value>
            classpath:location_of_config_file/hibernate.cfg.xml
        </value>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>

            ...    


        </props>    
    </property>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

The way I've done this before is by instantiating a [LocalSessionFactoryBean](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html) and setting the configLocation property.