# Hibernate-Spring Web container error

Tags: spring, hibernate, configuration

Hello I'm new to Hibernate.

I have generated with Hibernate Tools a database access module. The generator generates the code of the DAOS and Hibernate Beans.

When I test this module in a simple Java application all works fine, but when I test it in a Spring Web application I get a very strange error. Since my module is an independent jar it should access the database without regarding the circumstance of being executed in a simple Java application or a Web application. The code of my web application is:

```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public class Controller implements ApplicationContextAware
  {


   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


   @RequestMapping(value = "/purchased/songs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String home(Model model)
   {   

     SessionManager.startOperation();

     ChargeTryDAOBase ctdb=new ChargeTryDAOBase();

     List <ChargeTry> data=ctdb.findByRemoteId("dsfsdfsdf8");


     SessionManager.endOperation();

     model.addAttribute("result", "data" );

     return "home";
   }



   @Override
   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0) throws BeansException
   {
     this.applicationContext = arg0;
   }

}
```

When running this code on Tomcat I get following error:

```
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing
 nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
 org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;

    .....         

 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
 org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;
```

When I change some Hibernate dependencies I get following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI
```

When I test the above code in a simple Java application all works fine.

Is this a spring-hibernate configuration problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you configured all the required Hibernate Properties in Spring Configuration files? Can you post those also?

Comment: My Hibernate properties file is:

Comment: I have a single jar which encapsulates al database access functionality and in normal Java applications I only have to add this module to access database, it works form the scratch, but with Spring it doesnt work.

Comment: You have to work with Spring Hibernate configuration for this.

Comment: Where can I find an example for configuring my access module in Spring? I'm using Hibernate 4 and Tomcat 7. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please study

**1:** http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-and-spring-integration

and

**2** http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/

to get insight of Spring MVC and Hibernate Integration.

You can work with Hibernate Configuration file - here is the link -

[Spring and hibernate.cfg.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471799/spring-and-hibernate-cfg-xml)

But as your application is within a spring managed container, We will highly recommend to use applicationcontext.xml for better maintenance and management of codebase and performance.

Comment: But I have already an hibernate.cfg.xml inside my jar where I configure all properties of my datasource. Do I have to configure the properties specified in my hibernate.cfg.xml again in Spring? Thank you.

Comment: In Spring Container managed bean, it is a best practice in Spring to configure hibernate properties in applicationcontext.xml which is in 1st link above.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But is it possible to encapsulate all hibernate configuration in my hibernate.cfg.xml contained in my jar, not having to configure it in my upper Spring layer? Many thanks for your advice and help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have tested the configuration indicated in the link but I still get the same error. The strange thing is that I don't get a Spring context error, all seems to work but when: tx = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction(); gets executed, the error arises. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help finally I got all working. I followed your link and googled a little bit. The problem was that I didn't enable in my hibernate.cfg.xml file the datasource parameter, I also have configured C3P0 jdbc connection provider.

My final hibernate.cfg.xml file is:

```
  <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
       <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
       <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">userdb</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">12345</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb</property>
       <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
       <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>


       <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
       <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</property>
       <property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">4</property>
       <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
       <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
       <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property>
       <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1800</property>
       <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
```

In my web.xml I have added following lines:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>This is a MySQL database connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
```

In the Spring context file I have added following lines:

```
    <beans:bean id="dataSource"    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/> 
      <beans:property name="username" value="userdb"/>
      <beans:property name="password" value="12345"/> 
    </beans:bean>  

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <beans:property name="configLocation">
         <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
      </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

The strange thing is, that with the default Hibernate connection provider, the above solution didn't work but when I configured C3P0 all started to work.

Thank you for your help.