# Hibernate - cfg.xml Not Found in Resources

Tags: java, hibernate

**Edit:** Removed the spring snippets

Common issue but all the threads about this never managed to solve my issue.

Here's my very simple test setup:

```
public class HibernateSandboxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Configuration().configure();
    }
}
```

Project structure:

[image]

Why can't configure() find my cfg.xml in the resources folder?

Comment: This _looks_ like a Spring Boot project. If so, you shouldn't be configuring Hibernate anything manually; that's Boot's job. (That means both no `new Configuration()` _and_ no `cfg.xml`.)

Comment: It is but as I said to Kornejew even if I run it as just a normal java application Hibernate can't find the cfg.xml in my resources.

Comment: There is no "even if". You _should not_ run it as a "normal Java application"; you should be using `SpringApplication.run`, as I believe you originally got in your generated project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare it in the applicationContext.xml. Have a look here: [Spring and hibernate.cfg.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471799/spring-and-hibernate-cfg-xml)

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to load Hibernate on the side of Spring? After all you can run it standalone, how is Spring messing it up?

Either way, even if I remove all the Spring annotations so it's just ran as a simple main() Hibernate still can't find the cfg.xml file in the resources.

Comment: You can configure hibernate in spring in different ways. I personally prefer annotations and configuration classes. But application.yaml is great as well. If you just getting started I can highly recommend this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hibernate

Comment: Then I can ditch the cfg.xml all together and just have Spring read it in through application.properties from what I can see. Seems like the correct way to go as I want it as a Spring application but it still bothers me that Hibernate can't pick up the cfg.xml even if I run without Spring.